# Weird error declaring a vector in Java

Tags: java, vector

When I try to declare a vector in Java I'm getting an error that reads:
'Syntax error on token ";", expected "}" after this token'. I don't have any unclosed braces in my code. The line producing the error is listed below.I've googled the problem but I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
package gui;

import java.util.Vector;

public class PlayingCard {

    private String suit;
    private char rank;
    private int A = 1, T = 10, J = 10, Q = 10, K = 10;

    // available suits
    private String[] suits = {"spades", "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts"};

    Vector<String> possibleSuits = new Vector<String>(4);

    for(String currentSuit:suits){
        possibleSuits.add(currentSuit);
    }

}
```

Comment: paste your class code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the line you have provided. Could you please pass the entire class code?

Comment: Don't use `Vector`, it is (effectively) deprecated.

Comment: Are you importing `Vector`, and is that error the only error that you're getting?

Comment: @wassgren- code updated above

Comment: @chrylis- yes Importing Vector, and no I am actually getting onemore error on my closing brace for the class bizzarely. When I add another brace to the end of the code that error goes away while the original error remains

Comment: @BoristheSpider- thanks Borris, has a new data structure replaced it or should I just be using arrays? I could have just settled for an array but access a vector seemed a superior choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in some kind of code block such as a method, constructor or static initializer (between the curly braces `{ ... }`).

```
public class PlayingCard {
    // private members...

    // some method
    public void someMethod() {
        Vector<String> possibleSuits = new Vector<String>(4);

        // This loop must be executed in a code block
        for(String currentSuit:suits){
            possibleSuits.add(currentSuit);
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

See the following resources for more info:

- [Understanding class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [Basics about classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: Hmmm ... this is exactly what I wrote, earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because of the way your `for` loop is declared in the body of the class without being in a code block (I don't think this is legal) - you can either put the `for` loop in a method or put it in a code block enclosed by braces.